# Ansible lineinfile insertafter injects line at end of file

Tags: yaml, ansible

I'm using lineinfile as follows:

```
lineinfile dest=./hosts_exp insertafter='\[hosts1\]' line="xxxxxxxxx" state=present
```

My `hosts_exp` is as follows:

```
[local]
localhost

[hosts1]

[hosts2]

[hosts3]
```

lineinfile inserts the text after [hosts3] instead of inserting it after [hosts1].

Comment: What version of ansible are you using? I'm getting the expected result using your test, xxxxxxx is added after [hosts01].

Comment: @RamondelaFuente Now try after having line "xxxxxxxxx" already in your hosts_exp file. I mean try to add another same line.

Comment: Ansible's lineinfile module won't add the same line twice - the task is marked "ok" as I expect it to be.

Answer (score 7):

It appears redundant, but you need to specify the regex too:

```
lineinfile:
  dest: ./hosts_exp
  insertafter: '\[hosts1\]'
  regexp: '\[hosts1\]'
  line: "xxxxxxxxx"
  state=present
```

Why? The `regexp` says "look for this line". The `insertafter` says "inject the line here".

I tested this; [here's the commit](https://github.com/tedder/ansible-provisioning-simple/commit/81d13c3bd0dd62f71a23da1812870739179c62a1). There are a few minor changes in my commit from the line above, use as necessary.

Comment: It worked for me w/o regex, the issue was that it wasn't taking the same text again and again for insertion, I need to provide a new text and that aligns with my requirement here. Regex is not necessary.

Comment: To clarify, using the regex is only necessary if you do NOT want the line added if both regex and insertafter match.  So this is necessary if it should only be applied the first time which is the most common situation.

Answer (score 7):

use:

```
lineinfile:
  dest: "./hosts_exp"
  line: "xxxxxxxxx"
  insertafter: '^\[hosts1\]'
  state: present
```

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
- name: "blah"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/test.sh"
    insertafter: 'test text'
    line: "text add"
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backrefs: yes

```
lineinfile:
  backrefs: yes
  dest: ./hosts_exp
  insertafter: '\[hosts1\]'
  regexp: '\[hosts1\]'
  line: "xxxxxxxxx"
  state=present
```

This flag changes the operation of the module slightly; insertbefore and insertafter will be ignored, and if the regexp doesn't match anywhere in the file, the file will be left unchanged. If the regexp does match, the last matching line will be replaced by the expanded line parameter.