# Use lineinfile to fill ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have trivial task to fill particular ansible inventory file with the new deployed VMs names under their roles.
Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Add host to inventory file
    lineinfile: 
        dest: "{{inv_path}}"
        regexp: '^\[{{role}}\]'
        insertafter: '^#\[{{role}}\]'
        line: "{{new_host}}"
```

Instead of adding new line after [role], ansible replace the string with the hostname. My aim is to naturally insert after it. If there is no matched role it should skip add new line.

How to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some clarity to your last requirement?  Are you saying that you want to skip the entire task if `role` is not found in the inventory?  Also . you may want to take a look at dynamic inventories -
 http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#other-inventory-scripts?  It might make more sense to implement rather than a playbook that manages your inventories.

Comment: I'm provision VMware VMs from vRealize Automation. As a part of the whole workflow I need to add provisioned VMs to static Ansible inventory to be consumed later by DevOps team. This is how it have to work. During request user should specify the Ansible role for VM, if it's not in the inventory list, we will skip it

Answer (score 0):

`[role]` is getting replaced because the `regexp` parameter is the regular expression Ansible will look for to **replace** with the `line` parameter.  Just move that value to `insertafter` and get rid of `regexp`.

As for the other requirement you will need another task that will check if `[role]` exists first.  Then your lineinfile task will evaluate the result of the checker task to determine if it should run.

```
- name: Check if role is in inventory file
  shell: grep [{{ role }}] {{ inv_path }}
  ignore_errors: True
  register: check_inv

- name: Add host to inventory file
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ inv_path }}"
    insertafter: '^\[{{role}}\]$'
    line: "{{new_host}}"
  when: check_inv.rc == 0
```

Comment: Thanks, @kfreezy for your support. But I'm still can't manage it. Copy from my file: 
 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Check if role is in inventory file
    shell: grep [{{role}}] {{inv_path}}
    ignore_errors: True
    register: check_inv
    
  - name: Add host to inventory file
    lineinfile: 
        dest: "{{inv_path}}"
        insertafter: '^\[{{role}}\]$'
        line: "{{new_host}}"
    when: check_inv.rc == 0

Comment: What i found. first, I’m not sure, if the grep check really work. It return many lines if it doesn’t find role in inventory file.

administrator@ansible:~$ grep [bla-bla] /etc/ansible/ansible_alameda/inventories/dev/alameda_all.ini                                                                             [wsreportbuilder]
[alameda]
T1-shl08.test.local
administrator@ansible:~$

Second, it always adds my host to the EOF, not after [role]. It looks like similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173114/ansible-lineinfile-insertafter-injects-line-at-end-of-file

Comment: You're evaluating the return code from grep, not the number of lines. It'll return 0 if it finds something, otherwise it returns 1 or 2.  Try escaping the square brackets in `insertafter`.  `insertafter: "^\[{{ role }}\]$"`.  If that doesn't work try removing the '$' from the regex.  There might be an extra space at the end of the line.